# Plotting python pandas dataframe with timestamps as indices for x-axis shows iterating numbers

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, matplotlib

For some days I try to show timestamps on my a axis with pandas and Matplotlib. But for some reason it always shows some iterating numbers and I can't help myself on this.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

%matplotlib
plt.ion()

df = pd.read_csv('~/Development/ProgressionMovement/Data/03-02-pull/44#03-02_07-49_measurePoints.csv', index_col = 'timestamp', parse_dates = True)

for column in df.columns:
    if column != 'timestamp':
        df[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column], downcast='float')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for column in df.columns:
        if column != 'timestamp':
            df[column][index] = row[column] / 100

df.plot()
```

I tried a lot already, setting x_ticks, casting the index type into something else and more (I can't remember all of it). But I always only see these numbers. At best I would like to see the minutes and seconds only.

What am I doing wrong? This can't be that hard.

The csv looks like this:

[image]

And the plot like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright with some hints "vaughan is god" has given me I was able to show the right x labels. The code looks now like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as dates

%matplotlib
plt.ion()

df = pd.read_csv('~/Development/ProgressionMovement/Data/03-02-pull/44#03-02_07-49_measurePoints.csv', index_col = 'timestamp', parse_dates = True)

for column in df.columns:
    if column != 'timestamp':
        df[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column], downcast='float')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for column in df.columns:
        if column != 'timestamp':
            df[column][index] = row[column] / 100

ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(df.index)

xfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%M:%S:%f')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
df.plot()
```

It is a bit weird, but using the interactive plot tool, I have to run the last code block twice to show the seconds. Otherwise it shows me day, hours, minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Considering a figure created and ax1 being a subplot,
my go-to lines when plotting time on x axis are:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

ax1.set_xticks(datas)
```